# Шкала ценностей - синоним

Tags: лексика

Можно ли подобрать какой-нибудь синоним к этому выражению? В интернете ничего  путного не нашел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Система жизненных приоритетов.* Не совсем синоним, конечно...

Comment: Просто "жизненные приоритеты"? Без контекста трудно, конечно.

Comment: Матвей, хотел принять ваш вариант, принял другого. Вообще запутался!

Comment: Матвей, вы подали идею. Я выбрал вариант :жизненные приоритеты. Он более соответствует контексту.

Comment: Матвей, вариант неплохой , конечно. Но мне нужен не просто синоним, мне надо заменить ''шкалу ценностей'' в тексте. А это громоздкий вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Порядок/шкала приоритетов.
Но этот вариант несколько снижен по сравнению с первоначальным.

Comment: Да, мне нужен более книжный вариант.

Comment: @Серж Вариант "жизненые приоритеты" предложил Матвей, а не этот пользователь

Comment: Ой, да, спасибо. Запутался.

Answer (score 2):

(если нужно уйти от канцеляризмов типа "шкала/жизненная позиция/кредо" и пр.)

Взгляды на жизнь, миропонимание, мироощущение, убеждения, образ мыслей.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр. Ваши варианты, возможно, мне понадобятся в дальнейшем.

Answer (score 2):

Дайте, пожалуйста, контекст. Вне контекста синонимом может быть сочетание "жизненная позиция".

Comment: Да, возможен и такой вариант. Но я выбрал вариант:жизненные приоритеты. Он более соответствует контексту. Спасибо!